selenium crashed in multithreading on Ubuntu
I am working on building a large scraper where I need to interact with the target website search some filenames solve captchas using capsolver API and append data to Google Sheets. My target is to pull 15k records daily. I am using concurrent.futures for multithreading. When I run the code initially it works fine but when it exceeds 1500 records it keeps slowing down and eventually stops with the following exception:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid session id 

I run this on Ubuntu I know the problem is because of processes in multithreading which takes up so much memory and eventually crashes my scraper. But I don't have much experience in cleaning processes. Any help will be appreciated. While cleaning up processes I also want to preserve the state I want to start the scraper where we left it means it should again resume from the same file number.
def get_new_driver():
proxy = proxy_rotator.get_next_proxy()
return Driver(uc=True, headless=True, multi_proxy=True, proxy=proxy, no_sandbox=True, block_images=True)


def run_scraper(starting_file_number, end_file_number):

current_file_number = starting_file_number
driver = get_new_driver()

# Only for Debugging
# timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
# filename = f"screenshot_{timestamp}.png"

try:
    driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(SITE_URL, 10)

    csv_file = 'entity_details2.csv'

    while current_file_number <= end_file_number:
        try:
            search_entity(driver, current_file_number)

            form_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'form'))
            )
            form_text = form_element.text

            if 'Please complete the reCAPTCHA' in form_text:
                handle_recaptcha(driver, CAPSOLVER_API_KEY,
                                 SITE_KEY, SITE_URL)
                search_entity(driver, current_file_number)

            result = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tblResults'))
            )
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tblResults tr'))
            )

            # After ensuring rows are present, get them
            rows = result.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr')[
                1:]  # Exclude the first row

            for row in rows:
                td = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a')
                td.click()

                entity_details = scrape_entity_details(driver)
                print(entity_details)
                if entity_details:
                    append_to_csv(entity_details, csv_file)

                driver.back()

                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located(
                        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tblResults'))
                )
            current_file_number += 1
        except Exception as e:

            # Only for Debugging
            # timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
            # filename = f"screenshot_{timestamp}.png"
            # source_filename = f"screenshot_{timestamp}"
            # Take a screenshot and save it with the dynamic filename
            # driver.save_screenshot(filename)

            print(f"An error occurred for file number {
                  current_file_number}: {e}")

            msg = driver.title + ' Custpm Message'
            logger.warning(msg=msg)
            # if '502 Bad Gateway' in driver.title:
            driver.quit()
            driver = get_new_driver()
            print('Getting new driver...')
            driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(SITE_URL, 10)
            continue

finally:
    driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
# Number of concurrent scrapers you want to run
num_workers = 3

# Define ranges for different instances
# start_file_number = 4618981
# end_file_number = 4623981

start_file_number, end_file_number = get_file_numbers()
range_size = (end_file_number - start_file_number + 1) // num_workers

file_number_ranges = [
    (start_file_number + i * range_size,
     start_file_number + (i + 1) * range_size - 1)
    for i in range(num_workers)
]

# Ensure the last range extends to the end file number
file_number_ranges[-1] = (file_number_ranges[-1][0], end_file_number)

print(Fore.CYAN + "File number ranges for each worker:", file_number_ranges)

# Execute the scrapers
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(run_scraper, start, end)
               for start, end in file_number_ranges]

    for future in futures:
        future.result()

print("All scraping instances are done!")


you should include some sleep between quitting the driver and starting a new one.  (it should help a little to keep the sessionIDs straight...)  It'll be a little difficult to coordinate with multiple threads, though.  (coordinate threads with listener/notify logic)  Since this seems to happen when resources are low, you may be hitting a session timeout (which should be pretty long).  Reduce the number of threads or better yet, use a single grid node per machine for this.

I have been stuck on this for a week now. Some people give me suggestions for cleaning up the processes using psutil. I tried it it works on Windows but on Ubuntu, it's not working. Do you think it's a good idea or Can you please tell me about something grid I haven't used it before. By the way I am using t3.xlarge ec2 instance which has 4 cpu's and 16gb Ram.

Selenium Grid: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/
